# Cannot update dictionary

Tags: python-3.8

I have a dict_ class that attempts to copy the built-in dict class.

Here is that class (the `new` function returns the original object):

```py
class dict_:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.kv = kwargs

        if not self.kv:
            for kv in args:
                for k, v in kv:
                    self.kv.update({k: v})

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.kv

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.kv[item]

    def update(self, *args):
        self.kv.update(args)
```

I've called it like this:

```py
from Dodger.dodger import *

term = new(System())
a = new(dict_(a=1, b=2))
a.update(new(dict_(c=3)))
term.println(a)
```

This is supposed to modify a to `{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}` but instead it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/free_time/Dodger/dodger_test.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\free_time\Dodger\dodger.py", line 176, in update
  File "C:\free_time\Dodger\dodger.py", line 173, in __getitem__
KeyError: 0
```

Why is it giving a KeyError? What does the 0 mean? (I am using python 3.8.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this problem. I just have to implement `__setitem__` too:

```py
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    """Set self[key] to value"""
    self.kv[key] = value
```